# Can't display ng-repeat child scope property

Tags: angularjs

I need to display a list of data records using ng-repeat. Within every data object entry (a **coupon**) displyed, I need to grab some properties (**$scope.etabName** and **$scope.etabDistance**) from that object, do some calculations and show the result in the same data object's view within the ng-repeat view.

I've managed to do the calculations and when I console.log them the results are correct, but they are not showing correctly: the property displyed is the one relative to the last data object iterated by ng-repeat.

I know I'm not understanding the Angular way of doing scopes, so any help is welcome.

My controller:

```
$scope.getCouponList = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'JSONP',
        url: $scope.couponListUrl + "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&cookie=" + $localStorage.user.cookie +
        "&usr_latitude=" + $rootScope.lat + "&usr_longitude=" + $rootScope.lng
    }).
        success(function (data, status) {
            if (data.status && data.status == "ok") {
                $rootScope.couponList = data.list;
            }
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        });

    $scope.fetchEtabDetails = function($stateParams) {
        _.select($stateParams.etablissement, function (etab) {
            if (etab.id === $stateParams.etabcloser) {
                $scope.etabName = etab.name;
                $scope.etabDistance = etab.distance;
            }
        });
    };
};
```

My view:

```
<ion-content scroll="true" ng-controller="getCouponList">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item class="decline" ng-repeat="coupon in couponList"
                  ng-click="fetchCouponDetails(coupon)"
                  ng-init="fetchEtabDetails(coupon)">
          <div class="offer-image">
            <img class="full-image" ng-src="{{coupon.image_operation}}">

            <div class="offer-logo">
                <img ng-src="{{coupon.enseigne_logo_url}}">
            </div>

            <div class="offer-ens-name">
                <span>{{coupon.ens_name}}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="offer-name wrap-txt">
                <span>{{coupon.name}}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="offer-deadline-details">
                <i class="icon ion-android-time"></i>
                <timer countdown="coupon.diff_date" max-time-unit="'year'" interval="1000">{{ddays}}:{{hhours}}:{{mminutes}}</timer>
            </div>

            <div class="offer-zone">
                <i class="icon ion-location" class="etab"></i>
                <span>{{etabName}} {{etabDistance}} km</span>
            </div>

          </div>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: what error are you encountering?

Comment: @NitsanBaleli I'm not having errors, I just need to display "etabName" and "etabDistance" relative to each "coupon" iterated by the ng-repeat, what I get wrong is the last values for "etabName" and "etabDistance" of the last "coupon" that ng-repeat encounters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this function:

```
 $scope.fetchEtabDetails = function($stateParams) {
    _.select($stateParams.etablissement, function (etab) {
        if (etab.id === $stateParams.etabcloser) {
            $scope.etabName = etab.name;
            $scope.etabDistance = etab.distance;
        }
    });
```

You only have 1 $scope.etabName.  Each call is overwriting it.

I would do this...

```
 $scope.fetchEtabDetails = function($stateParams) {
    _.select($stateParams.etablissement, function (etab) {
        if (etab.id === $stateParams.etabcloser) {
            $stateParams.etabName = etab.name;
            $stateParams.etabDistance = etab.distance;
        }
    });
```

then in your HTML...

```
<div class="offer-zone">
    <i class="icon ion-location" class="etab"></i>
    <span>{{coupon.etabName}} {{coupon.etabDistance}} km</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks, I managed to get the same result using some filtering in the view with "data-ng-repeat" and "ng-if", but I've used your solution because it's more logic.